Why do I get the error SPLIT parameter 1 empty error when it isn't?
I'm using the formula below to divide numbers in the format (EX:2/4/6/8) from column E by the number in column D (EX: 2) and provide output in the same format from column E (1/2/3/4).
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((ROW(D2:D) = 4) + (ROW(D2:D) = 9) + (D2:D = "") + (E2:E = "") + (D2:D = 0), "", TEXTJOIN("/", TRUE, SPLIT(E2:E, "/") / D2:D)))
The error I'm receiving is that in rows that have values and aren't being skipped by the IF (4 and 9), I'm receiving the error saying "Function SPLIT parameter 1 value should be non-empty." I don't understand how this could be the case since the formula should be skipping the rows where parameter 1 is empty in the first place, and the error occurs in rows where it shouldn't be empty. I have no experience with spreadsheets like this but understand the code and can't find anything that seems like it would cause the error so any help is greatly appreciate!

Although I don't completely understand why you are using ROW. I think the issue within your code is first, the if condition will always result in "FALSE" since you are using +, then your else (false) condition does not really divide each value of column E to D since your arrayformula does not cover the values within the split function.
Now, if your goal is to split the values in column E, then divide each with the value of column D, then join them together. I have crafted a solution that you may try.
Complete formula:
=MAP(D2:D,E2:E, LAMBDA(x,y, IF(OR(x = 0, x = "", y = ""), "",JOIN("/", BYCOL(SPLIT(y, "/"), LAMBDA(c, TEXT(c/x, "0.00")))))))

Sample result:



Divided by
values
Answer result




2
2/4/6/8
1.00/2.00/3.00/4.00


3
3/6/9/12
1.00/2.00/3.00/4.00


0
2/4/6/8



2




2
10/20/30
5.00/10.00/15.00


0
5/10/15/20



2
2/4/2006
1.00/2.00/1003.00


2
2/4/6/8/10
1.00/2.00/3.00/4.00/5.00


2
5/10/15
2.50/5.00/7.50


3
12/15/18/21
4.00/5.00/6.00/7.00


4
0/16/24/32
0.00/4.00/6.00/8.00



References:

BYCOL
Map


Feel free to leave a comment if you have any questions with regards to the posted answer above. If this is not your expected result, please create a minimal reproducible example, etc. This way, the community members will have better visualization of your issue.

I don't know why I was using ROW either I just found a few resources and was trying to put them together. Thank you so much for finding a solution! Is there a way to round to 2 decimal places? I tried this, which is simply adding ROUND( , 2) outside of the TEXTJOIN but it removed any number after the first. =MAP(D2:D,E2:E, LAMBDA(x,y, IF(OR(x = 0, x = "", y = ""), "", TEXTJOIN("/", TRUE, ROUND(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(y, "/") / x), 2))))

Hello, Thank you for your reply. I have updated my code to cater your additional inquiry of adding 2 decimal places between integers. Please do not hesitate to add a comment if you have any questions. Otherwise, kindly accept and upvote my answer if you think that it was useful and met your expected result.
